# how can pass custom params to rest get url?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, input-parameters

I need to have a URL for passing parameters to my rest server like below:
http://localhost:8080/myprojectName/resrtApp?Name=$Name&LastName=$LastName&Message=$Message&UserId=$UserId

I used jersey for my rest server. how can I define this pattern in @Path?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using the queryparam I think. An example is [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-queryparam-example/)